# My crypto exchange closed my account for no reason, how can I defend myself against it?

Tags: cryptocurrency

A couple of years ago, I opened an account in **Bitpanda**, deeming it a serious and professional crypto exchange.

In the last year I haven't carried out any operations, a few days ago I decided to go back to do some trading.

I had to supplement my account with new personal info, selfies and photos of my passport.
All approved, so I moved to the platform, click on deposit, where I noticed that the maximum deposit I could make was 0 euros. Then I tried to make a withdrawal, but that too was disabled.

So I contacted the support and this is what they told me:

> After a further check by our security department, we have to
> permanently close your account for security reasons. Also, it is not
> possible to create a new account or reactivate an existing one.
>
> Please note that we cannot provide any further information on this
> decision and will not deal with any complaints about it.

The bottom line is that they actually stole my money, for no reason, as I have never done any weird transactions.

Even if it's little money, it seems to me an injustice. **Is there anything I can do about this action?**

**UPDATE 2 JAN 2023**

On December 29th, I opened a dispute and after 4 days with no response, I look at my ticket directly on the website, so what a surprise when I saw that my dispute was closed without any reason.

Comment: Small claims court. Good luck. Obviously if they close your account they have to repay all the money in it. If they have any.

Comment: @gnasher729 The fact is that they didn't close my account, in fact I can access it easily... but they have disabled any use of it. Smart huh?

Comment: What jurisdiction does your contract specify? Also, does your contract outline any administrative remedies and/or methods for dispute resolution?

Comment: @IñakiViggers I couldn't find the contract, it's not in my account, and even in emails there's no trace of it, but as specified on the website it should be Vienna | Austria...as you suggested I found a [link](https://www.bitpanda.com/it/legal/legal-notice/bitpanda-issuance-gmbh) to open a dispute

Comment: @NineCattoRules, the downvote isn't from me, but I can guess why and also why the two close votes as of right now. If you think that it is *fraud*, file a crime report with the police. If not, get more precise in your terms.

Comment: @o.m. I'm not a lawyer, the term fraud was used simply from its etymological meaning. 1. Act or behaviour intended to deceive a third party's right: steal, obtain...

Comment: @NineCattoRules, half of the time you write as if you have a *criminal* complaint, half of the time you write as if you have a *civil* complaint. Different issues. I presume you want your money, with a criminal conviction at best a secondary objective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My crypto exchange closed my account for no reason, how can I defend myself against such a fraud?

Since you [cannot find the contract](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/87674/my-crypto-exchange-closed-my-account-for-no-reason-how-can-i-defend-myself-agai?noredirect=1#comment196668_87674), it is unclear how exactly to proceed (at least for someone not enough knowledgeable on the matter) or the *competent authority* in the jurisdiction (Member State) at issue. But article 5.3 of the [Directive 2002/65/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=celex%3A32002L0065) provides:

> At any time during the contractual relationship the consumer is
> entitled, at his request, to receive the contractual terms and
> conditions on paper.

The exchange's response suggests that it terminated your contract despite your compliance with its requests for further information. That conduct appears to be elusive of its duty pursuant to art. 5.3 and other obligations.

The European Securities and Markets Authority has a brief guideline on [filing a complaint](https://www.esma.europa.eu/investor-corner/file-complaint). In case that the exchange qualifies(?) as "trade repository" [see this link](https://www.esma.europa.eu/supervision/trade-repositories). That being said, on most issues the ESMA ultimately directs clients to the Member State's *competent authority*.

Article 95 of the [MICA draft](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A52020PC0593) alludes to the publication of decisions regarding complaints against financial entities. Although it is still a draft, this provision is no different from enactments on other topics (financial and otherwise). Some research on decisions from the applicable jurisdiction likely will give guidance on how to proceed, since [quasi-]judicial publications often provide some procedural background of the controversy being decided.

Regardless of whether or not the matter presents all the elements of *fraud*, the scenario you describe sounds in --at least-- *breach of contract*.

Answer (score 4):

1. **Think through what really happened.**
   You are using terms like fraud, while they *may* be thinking they're doing fraud protection, or otherwise following laws and regulations. You wrote that you didn't use it for a long time, could the credentials have been compromised?
   It sounds highly implausible that a platform would defraud a *single* user. Either there are many more people with similar stories, or your claim is a bit suspect.
2. **Think about what your goal is.**
   Reactivating the account, or getting the balance back? Is the balance big enough to spend time and money?
3. **Check with which legal entity you have a contract.**
   AFAIK BitPanda is Austrian, so they cannot refuse a GDPR information request on what they have about *you* all that easily. Consider communication in writing, by registered mail.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141652/discussion-on-answer-by-o-m-my-crypto-exchange-closed-my-account-for-no-reason).